# Printing rows in a table for RTF using XML Publisher

Tags: rtf, jdedwards, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I have a requirement where I need to print table records as shown in image (two tables - column M, N, O, P, Q for reference). Where record should print from left side of table then continue to print on right side of table . I need to use oracle XML publisher to achieve this requirement.

I am not sure if its possible to print like that using XML publisher / any kind of table script or formatting with RTF files.

Can anyone help to suggest if its possible? If yes how to do it? any links to refer.

To add-on; This report is to be printed from ERP JD Edwards using XML Publisher or if possible using JDE Reporting tool using tabular / columnar / generic layout format (mostly not possible with reporting tool).

[image: Table Specs for Reference]